# How do I extract / retrieve the full link to a attachment file inside a InfoPath 2007 form?

Tags: 2007, infopath, attachments, jpg

Suppose that a user have attached a `Jack.jpg` file as a attachment to a online InfoPath 2007 form, is there a way to retrieve or extract the full URL of this attachment file `Jack.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

If I haven't misunderstood your situation, the attachment files are stored as blob data inside the xml of the form, so there's no permanent URL for the image.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be stored as a Base64 encoded string inside the XML file.  I would suggest writing a custom .aspx page which takes a querystring parameter to identify the document that can retrieve the raw XML and convert the Base64 encoded attachment into binary and send it back to the browser.

Comment: Yip, correct answer. All Sharepoint content is stored within Content DBs. You have to do a response.write of the byte[] which represents the image/file